# Select empty element in TinyMCE on click

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I would like to have the behaviour of the img element applied to another inline element: when clicking on it, it should get selected.

Specifically, I'd like to have an empty q or span tag and when the user clicks on it he should be able to add some attributes. I've written a plugin that works similar to the link-button but it doesn't work for empty elements because they never get selected in the first place. The reason for all this is that I want to replace these elements on the server with a footnote generated from the saved attributes.

I found how it's done for the img element, from tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce_src.js:

```
        // Workaround for bug, http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12250
        // WebKit can't even do simple things like selecting an image
        // This also fixes so it's possible to select mceItemAnchors
        if (tinymce.isWebKit) {
            t.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
                e = e.target;

                // Needs tobe the setBaseAndExtend or it will fail to select floated images
                if (e.nodeName == 'IMG' || (e.nodeName == 'A' && dom.hasClass(e, 'mceItemAnchor'))) {
                    t.selection.getSel().setBaseAndExtent(e, 0, e, 1);
                    t.nodeChanged();
                }
            });
        }
```

But when I try to copy and adapt this I run into the problem taht e.target is already the surrounding paragraph element instead of the empty q element I clicked on (I've styled it with CSS's :before pseudoclass). At least on WebKit that's what happens. In Firefox it actually works, when using a double click instead of a single click.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it is possible to select it using javascript (using an id), but the problem here will be to detect the case where/when you want to select it. can you describe that case a bit more?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like to select it when I click on it (even though it's an empty tag I can style it with CSS to have heigth/width and :before content). I tried the onclick-attribute but then tinyMCE was undefined..

Comment: you should use the tinymce onClick handler: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onClick

Comment: hmm, you could try and see if this element got the focus, then assign a blur-handler and know when to remove the class 'selected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working! Thank you Thariama for your help :)
Note: important is that the q element is styled with `display: inline-block;` Otherwise you'll never be able to select it.

```
//makes an empty q.citation tag selectable
ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
    e = e.target;
    var dom = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom;
    if (e.nodeName == 'Q' && dom.hasClass(e, 'citation') ) {
        ed.selection.select(e);

        //add class 'selected' for styling
        dom.addClass(e, 'selected');
        ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
            //remove class 'selected'
            dom.removeClass(e, 'selected');
        });
    }
});
```